# prevent beforeSelectRow event, when a user doubleClick any Row in jqgrid

Tags: events, jqgrid, event-handling

I am using cell editing in jqgrid and for that, i am using many different jqgrid events, as mentioned below ...
1) beforeSelectRow, 2)beforeEditCell, 3)afterEditCell, 4)onCellSelect, 5)ondblClickRow, etc...

Now, when i doubleClick on any of the row, the beforeselectRow code gets executed first.. which i want to prevent... but how to do that ??

Some example code is as below :-

```
ondblClickRow: function(id,irow,icol,e)
{
  ........
},
beforeSelectRow : function(rowid, e) 
{   

    if(rowid==lastSelected)
    {
        $sampleDialog.dialog('open');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different web browsers process the double-click event in a little different ways. So in general you can't prevent 'click' event before 'dblclick'. The callback `beforeSelectRow` will be called inside of `click` enevt handler defined inside of jqGrid code. In jQuery documentation of `dblclick` event handler you can read the following (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)):

> It is inadvisable to bind handlers to both the `click` and `dblclick`
>   events for the same element. The sequence of events triggered varies
>   from browser to browser, with some receiving two `click` events before
>   the `dblclick` and others only one. Double-click sensitivity (maximum
>   time between clicks that is detected as a double click) can vary by
>   operating system and browser, and is often user-configurable.

What you currently do is just not recommended way to binding *both* 'click' and 'dblclick' handles.

You don't describe the original problem which you has which is probably somewhere inside of `ondblClickRow` callback implementation. The only solution will be to examine reorganization of the program to have no collisions between the actions inside of `beforeSelectRow` and `ondblClickRow` callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the help ...!! Have removed similar code from beforeSelectRow (which was useful though), thus now not getting that problem.. but still using some timeout and all, can't we prevent the click event for double click.. ??

Comment: Sorry, for the accept miss.. except this question, i did for all your other answers... i just missed this one.. !! Was speaking about jquery's settimeout function.. By giving some time out, using setTimeOut function, in click event.. can't we prevent execution of click event code, on doubleclick ..

Comment: @mayur: The double-click will be fire *after* the click so it's **too late** to do some action to prevent the click event. You should reorganize your code so that the problem which you want to prevent don't exist at all. I can't explain more detailed because you don't described in details what your program do in both event handlers and why the problem exist. Moreover you should be accurate. The are JavaScript function `setTimeout` and no "jquery's settimeout function" or "setTimeOut function". I think that you should explain your existing problem on an code example.

Comment: As per my first comment.. i have organized the code properly.. and now.. m not facing any problem.. was asking this for curiosity sake.. so that if in future, again such problems arise in any other plugins ..!!   and again you are right.. its javascript function only.. !!

Comment: @mayur: I can try to help you to solve theome problem only if I'll see the code which shows exactly what you do. Sorry, but after all your explanations I still have no idea what your program do inside on row selection and on double-click and why you have the problem at all, so I just unable to help you.

Comment: Its alright.. as i have changed the code.. and organized properly as you told.. i can't get you the one giving problem.. but anywayz.. thanks for the help.. !!

Comment: @mayur: You are welcome! It's good to know that the problem is solved.