# jqGrid: Select the text of a row on inline editing

Tags: jqgrid, selection, inline-editing

I have a grid and I'm using PHP and JSON. I'm using ondblClickRow to do inline editing. The thing that I need is: when I double click in a field, I want the content of this field will be select. I'm sorry to ask about this, but I didn't find this... when I search it on Google I just find examples of select row and this issues.

Comment: What web browser you use? The order of `click` and `dblclick` events can be different in different web browsers. You can't prevent selection in case of `dblclick` if the `click` will be the first. You can only unselect the clicked line inside of `dblclick` event if it is really required.

Comment: I'm using Firefox. Hummm I didn't know that! Thanks @Oleg. So I think I will have to change something to get a way to do this. Thanks again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176888/315935) and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8999693/315935). Probably modification of the code from the last answer to the web browser which you use will get your the solution of your problem.

Comment: @mzs_newbie: Probably the second part of [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8334227/315935) could be helpful you too. It shows how to select text inside of cells. Using the same API you can unselect the text too. See [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3169849/315935), [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975178(v=vs.85).aspx) in addition.

Comment: Once again... thanks @Oleg! You are always ready to help those who needs it! :D

Comment: @mzs_newbie: If I understand you correctly you should select the text inside of [oneditfunc](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) callback of inline editing. The callback will be called *after* all input controls are created. Alternatively you can do this inside of [dataInit](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions).

Comment: Almost work... but this disable the double click on a row to inline edit. What I would like to do is to double click then go to a inline edit and at the same time select the text of the field that I clicked. I would try to put this in `oneditfunc` but I'm already using this to implement the autocomplete :/ Can you help me?

Comment: Hummm so do I have to implement this inside `dataInit`? Or which is the best option? Implement autocomplete inside `oneditfunc` or `dataInit`?

Comment: @mzs_newbie: If you need to do some additional actions inside of input control of some column (for example call `autocomplete`, select the text etc) then `dataInit` will be the best choice. If you need to do some actions after *all controls of the line will be created* then `oneditfunc` will be the best choice.

Comment: @mzs_newbie: I don't understand what you mean under "disable the double click".

Comment: Hummm now I got it!
Ohh I'm sorry, I wrote this in the wrong way... What I mean is that when I double click just select the text and I can't edit the row... I'm sorry sometimes I don't know how to express myself :)

Comment: And just one more thing... Can I do more than one "operation" inside `dataInit`?

Comment: @mzs_newbie: I though that you called `editRow` inside of `ondblClickRow`. I do this permanently in productive grids which I create. It allows to view grid like without any editing mode, but using double-click starts inline editing. I don't have problems with selection of the text.

Comment: @mzs_newbie: `dataInit` is just callback function. It can be so long as required. So you can do multiple operations of the editing controls (on `<input>` for example).

Comment: Humm so where do you call to select text? Omg! Thank you so much @Oleg! Now the things are clearer! Thanks again! Best regards :)

Comment: @Oleg... could you help me with this question? [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433876/autocomplete-datainit)

Comment: @mzs_newbie: I am asked to help by answering on questions from many people. I have to make my main job too (which bring me and my family money :-)). I'll came to your question later after I'll finish some other things which I am doing currently.

Comment: I'm sorry!!! Ok, no problem. I can wait the time you need! I just need your help :) Thank you so much and I'm sorry to bother you" :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single cell to be **focused** after inline edit mode is enabled, try this:

```
ondblClickRow: function (rowId, rowIndex, columnIndex) {
  var grid = $('#mygrid');
  grid.editRow(rowId, true, function() {
    var colModel = grid.getGridParam('colMode');
    var colName = colModel[colIndex].name;
    var input = $('#' + rowId + '_' + colName);
    input.get(0).focus();
  });
}
}
```

Found the code here:
http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/setting-focus-on-a-cell-after-entering-edit-mode/

Comment: Not a cell, but a row... I just want to put focus in that cell that I'm clicking and select the content... so do you think I have to implement cell edit too? Thanks

Comment: Cell edit is for editing a single cell rather than a whole row. So you want the user to be able to double-click a row, have the row be in edit inline mode, but have the cell that the user double-clicked focus? I don't think that's possible, because the initial double-click happens on the row itself. After that, the editable elements are created. I think the user is just going to have to explicitly click the cell that they want to edit after the initial double-click.

Comment: Huuumm so so... I want to double click in a row, but when I click I want to select the content of the first field or the field that I'm with the cursor. So do you think this is possible @Rob?

Comment: I still don't understand what it is you are trying to do. Are you trying to edit a single cell? Or are you only trying to select a single cell (not editing at all)?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't so clear...
I want to double click and edit a row. But when the row is enabled to edit I want that the content of a cell be selected without I'm doing this by myself. Did you understand me or I'm not so clear yet?

Comment: Oook! Thanks @Rob! :D Just one more doubt... I'm using remote data. Is the same to implement with remote data?

Answer (score 0):

If you have specific columns in a grid when you click on it should select its contents, then in your colmodel add this code to each column:

```
{
    name: 'TEXT_BOX',
    index: 'TEXT_BOX',
    label: 'Notes',
    width: 100,
    align: 'left',
    sortable: false,
    hidden: false, 
    dataEvents: [ { type: 'click', data: { i: 7 }, fn: function(e) { e.target.select(); } }] 
}
```

`dataEvents` will select the text in the input field when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Text will get Selected of cell when inline editing 
    $('#gridTableObj').jqGrid({
        ....
        ..
        afterEditCell : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol){
            $('#'+rowid+'_'+cellname).select(); // with this the edited cell value will be selected.            
        }
        ...
        ..

    });
```