# Autocomplete dataInit

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-autocomplete, double-click, inline-editing

I'm trying to use jQuery UI Autocomplete inside a jqGrid in the `dataInit`. I'm doing it like this:

```js
{ name:'ac_fin_g', index:'ac_fin_g', width:75, editable: true, edittype: 'text',
    editoptions: {
        dataInit: function (elem) {
            $(elem).autocomplete({
                source: 'autocomplete.php',
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    #('ac_fin_g').val(ui.item.value);
                }
            });
        }
   }}
```

And in the function `ondblClickRow` I'm passing `select` like a parameter:

```js
ondblClickRow: function (id, select) {
    if (id) {
        if (id !== lastSel) {
            $('#list').restoreRow (lastSel);
            $('#list').editRow (id, true, select);
            lastSel = id;
        } else {
            $('#list').restoreRow (lastSel);
            lastSel = "";
        }
    }
}
```

This is working but just for the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the main reason of your problem is wrong usage of `ondblClickRow` callback. The second parameter of `ondblClickRow` callback is the index of the row in the grid. There are other option which you can use. The most full prototype of `ondblClickRow` callback contains 4 parameters:

```js
// one can use ondblClickRow: function (id) { below because iRow, iCol, e are not used
ondblClickRow: function (id, iRow, iCol, e) {
    var $self = $(this);
    if (id !== lastSel) {
        $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", lastSel);
        lastSel = id;
    }
    $self.jqGrid("editRow", id, true);
}
```

The third parameter of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) is `oneditfunc` callback. The usage of `iRow` number as `oneditfunc` callback is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Oleg! I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you mean :(

Comment: @mzs_newbie: `ondblClickRow` is callback function. All parameters of the functions are defined by jqGrid and you can't change it. You used `ondblClickRow: function (id, select) { ... $('#list').editRow (id, true, select); ...}` in your code. So you forward 2-nd parameter of `ondblClickRow` (which you name as `select` and which I named `iRow`) as 3-d parameter during calling of `editRow`. It's wrong.

Comment: Ohhh ok. I understood now. Thanks. I changed everything but it's still not working.

Comment: @mzs_newbie: What is not working now? Do you removed `$('#list').restoreRow (lastSel);` from the `else` part see `ondblClickRow`? I am not sure also that `select` callback of `autocomplete` is required.

Comment: Now it's still the same that before... The edit and autocomplete just work for the first row. Yes, I changed everything you said, and I also removed select.

Comment: @mzs_newbie: Could you include the data which returns `'autocomplete.php'`?

Comment: of course! :D I'm sorry the delay but I just could reply you today. The 'autocomplete.php' has: `SQL`: `$SQL = "SELECT DISTINCT ac_fin_g FROM circ_69 WHERE ac_fin_g ILIKE '%".$term."%'";
     $result = pg_query( $con, $SQL ) or die ("Couldn't execute query." . pg_last_error())` And now the part of the return: `$i=0; while($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) { $response[] = row[ac_fin_g]; $i++; } echo json_encode($response); `

Comment: @mzs_newbie: Could you post example of **the data** not the code. In the case I could save the server response in the file and I would try to reproduce the problem without having your server.

Comment: Humm ok, I'm sorry. For example, if I write `"U"` it returns me: `["ILUMIN    ","ROTA FUGA "]`. The way that I'm returning the data is wrong?

Comment: @mzs_newbie: Try with [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/mzs_newbie.htm). It's almost what you posted. I don't see any problems. By the way the code `#('ac_fin_g').val(ui.item.value);` which you posted means sure `$('#ac_fin_g').val(ui.item.value);`. Look at the code of the demo. I used `dataInit: function (elem) {var $elem = $(elem);$elem.autocomplete({source: 'autocomplete.php', select: function (event, ui) { $elem.val(ui.item.value); }});}`

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried but it's still not working. I think is something that I'm missing... I will try to fix this and later I let you know about it! But once again thanks for you time and your help! :) You are always helpful!

Comment: @mzs_newbie: You are welcome! Do you have the demo with the bug online available? In the case I could just look at full demo. Probably the reason is very easy, but you just don't post the information which is the real origin of the problem. If you can provide live demo, please use non-minimized version (`jquery.jqGrid.src.js`) of jqGrid in the demo and post me just the link (URL) to the demo.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have :( But I can put in some site that provides a temporary hosting file and maybe you can look from there? I had another version of the code, and I tried to change it and now it's working, but I don't know what's wrong with the other version.

Comment: @mzs_newbie: Do you verified that you filled `id` of rows correctly in the demo which doesn't work? Probably you have some id duplicates in the demo?

Comment: Thank you so much! I found it! In the response of my php.php file (that is the file that I fill the grid) I wasn't returning the `id` so I didn't have something to identify the row. Thanks for all and I'm sorry for the newbie questions!!! :)

Comment: @mzs_newbie: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you.